# Rotation of wobj vertices using Euler angles

Tags: matlab, rotation, wavefront

**Hello experts!**

I have an Euler rotation matrix:

```
a11 = cos(psi)*cos(phi) - cos(theta)*sin(phi)*sin(psi);
a12 = cos(psi)*sin(phi) + cos(theta)*cos(phi)*sin(psi);
a13 = sin(psi)*sin(theta);
a21 = -sin(psi)*cos(phi) - cos(theta)*sin(phi)*cos(psi);
a22 = -sin(psi)*sin(phi) + cos(theta)*cos(phi)*cos(psi);
a23 = cos(psi)*sin(theta);
a31 = sin(theta)*sin(phi);
a32 = -sin(theta)*cos(phi);
a33 = cos(theta);

rotationMatrix = [a11 a12 a13; a21 a22 a23; a31 a32 a33]
```

I'm sure the rotation matrix is correct. The problem occurs when I try to apply a rotation to a wobj file (a box in this case).

I want to rotate a box which looks like:

```
vertices =

 0     0     0
 0     2     0
 0     2     2
 0     0     2
 2     0     2
 2     0     0
 2     2     0
 2     2     2
```

If I do:

```
rot= rotationMatrix*vertices'
```

and then turn the vertices back around again after the rotation

```
FV.vertices = rot'
```

I get a wrong rotation. Can anyone help me out please?

Illustration of the problem:
[image: The box is not rotated like the red system (X,Y,Z)]

Comment: Which Euler sequence is this?

Comment: The local z-axis has coordinates `(a13,a23,a33)`. Does this come out when you draw the vector (red z-axis) above?

Comment: @ja72 This is the x-convention if that is what you mean? The rotated system is rotated with a matrix 2*eye(3) and is working fine. If I limit the vertices so that they match the object:
    v 2 0 0
    v 0 2 0
    v 0 0 2
They rotate correctly. The problem occurs, when i try to include more than three vertices.

Comment: There are multiple sequences of Euler angles and I was wondering which one you are using. For example `ZYX`, `YZX`, `ZXZ`, etc.

Comment: I use ZXZ as described here: [Euler angles](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerAngles.html)